# Problem of selection after a subdivision surface

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, vertices

I can't understand why, after the apply of my sub surface, when i try to select all the mesh with <kbd>a</kbd>, the result come out is very weird (never seen before). From this

[image]

Clicking <kbd>a</kbd>

[image]

This is the file. Try to apply the modifier and select all the mesh with <kbd>a</kbd>. What could be the problem?

[image]

I can't figure out. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no problem with selection, but with so many edges, the edge info : Length looks messy.
[image: selection1]
You just need to deactivate it.
[image: selection2]

Comment: Oh . . . i fell stupid right now . . . thank you so much